# Not Finding Empty Array Values in Object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I am trying to understand why when I run the following code, none of the props return as `true` for being arrays. `addresses` and `emails` should return true I would think, and yet they return `false`.

```
let obj1 = {
  name: 'John',
  age: 42,
  addresses: [],
  emails: []
}


function findArrays(obj) {
  for (let propName in obj) {
    console.log(propName, Array.isArray(propName));
    // All values console.log as false
 }
}

findArrays(obj1);
```

Answer (score 3):

You iterate over the *keys of the object* (which are all strings, e.g. `"emails"`). The arrays are *values of the object*. To access the value stored under a specific key, use `obj[propName]`.

Answer (score 0):

`propName` is string  but `obj[propName]` is array.